# How many ones required to get to $n$?

Tags: number-theory

So, any natural number can be written as the sum or difference of ones. For example, we can write the number $5$ as $1+1+1+1+1=5$. However, we can write the number $11$ as $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=11$ or $11=11$. We can also write $7$ as $1+1+1+1+1+1+1=7$ or $11-1-1-1-1=7$. My question is that is there a way to determine what the minimum number of ones can be used to make any natural number $n$. So in the example of $11$, only $2$ ones are required even though we can write it as the sum of multiple ones. Also, $7$ can be written with only $6$ ones as I showed above.

Comment: Using what operations?  Concatenation (*otherwise 11 isn't allowed, implying things like 111 and 1111 are allowed*), addition, and subtraction... any others?  Can you concatenate results of operations?  For example $(1)\circ (1+1)=12$ where $\circ$ denotes the concatenation operation?

Comment: Only addition or subtraction and concatenation is allowed, so 11 can work 111, etc.

Comment: That only answers the first half of my question for clarification.  Is $(1)\circ(1+1)$ allowed?

Comment: No that can't work

Comment: Final question for clarification that I can think of, when you use, say, $111+1=112$, do you say that four ones were used or two?

Comment: four ones were used

Comment: Basically you are asking for a general formula for a lower bound?

Comment: @MarcoDisce Yes I was wondering if there exists a way to find the minimum number of ones used. A general formula would be perfect

Comment: A rewording/formalization of the question then given my understanding:  minimize $|a_1|+2|a_2|+3|a_3|+\dots+i|a_i|+\dots$ subject to $a_11 + a_2 11+a_3111+\dots+a_i \underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{i~\text{times}} +\dots = n$ with each $a_i\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes i think that's what I am looking to do

Comment: I should expect, (*but am not about to put in the effort to prove*) that such an expression for a specific $n$ can be created algorithmically by taking your running total and adding or subtracting the number $\underbrace{11\cdots 1}$ such that $|\text{running total} - n|$ is minimized.  Repeat the process.  E.g. start with runningtotal=0.  $|240-(0+x)|$ is minimized with $x=111$.  Set new running total=111.  $|240-(111+x)|$ is minimized with $x=111$.  Set new running total=111+111.  $|240-(111+111 + x)|$ is minimized with $x=11$.  Repeating the process, we have $240=111+111+11+11-1-1-1-1$

Comment: If a tie occurs, then use the value for $x$ which uses fewer $1$'s.  E.g. $n=6$.  $|6-x|$ is minimized for $x=1$ and $x=11$ (both result in $|6-x|=5$).  What remains is to prove that algorithm is in fact the most efficient (*or to disprove or come up with a better one*), and to create a closed form expression for the expression(which I expect will look terribly convoluted and ugly).